# Caching configs in Spree ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

When I update spree config via admin panel `Spree::Config[some_key] = some_value` it overwrites the value in a spree_preferences table, but also store previous versions of value and use all these versions.
`Rails.cache.clear` do not help. But restart a unicorn helped me.

Where are these versions stored? 
How can I explicitly reset the cached values ​​in the code?

Comment: Have you had a read of the docs [here](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/preferences.html)? There's a lot in there that could be handy. It covers where they're stored, inheritance, initialisers among plenty of other useful areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the caching of unicorn workers.